# I am trying to add two buttons in the center of an image overlapping it using plain HTML

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add two buttons that overlap an image with a `HREF`, also I am using the Bootstrap Framework and want to use -Danger and -Success types of buttons rectangles too. The image in my local folder is: `Images/RL.jpg`
Thanks guys!

```html
<img src="images/rl.jpg" />
<center>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Success</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Danger</button>
</center>
```

Comment: can you show some code or add fiddle here

Comment: Yes but all it is so far is img src"images/rl.jp"

Comment: Please post a **minimal working example** of your code (HTML/CSS/JS) in a [Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See [mcve] and [ask].

Comment: <img src="images/rl.jpg" <center><button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Success</button><center><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Danger</button></center>

Answer (score 0):

You can use `background-image` instead of `img` tag.

Also, you can use the class `.text-center` instead of using `center` tag (which is bad practice anyway)

Something like this:

```css
.wrapper {
  background:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/XIoGh.jpg);
  padding: 150px 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="wrapper text-center">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Success</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Danger</button>
</div>
```